# How to load multiple documents based on ids?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to load a set of ids from mongodb in C# to a list. Can anyone help to suggest any collection or filter method of mongodb? I'm very new to this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @Llama, you can also use `Expression` to achieve the same result.

```cs
var documentIds = GetDocumentIds();
var documents = await mongoContext
    .GetCollection<MyModel>("collectionName")
    .Find(model => documentIds.Contains(model.Id))
    .ToListAsync();
```

You can also use the `Linq` extensions from `MongoDB.Driver.Linq` namespace.

```cs
var documents = await mongoContext
    .GetCollection<MyModel>("collectionName")
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(model => documentIds.Contains(model.Id))
    .ToListAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a model something like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
}
```

You can use `In`:

```
List<ObjectId> documentsToLoad = getDocumentsToLoad();

List<MyModel> documents = await myCollection
    .Find(
        Builders<MyModel>.Filter.In(m => m.Id, documentsToLoad)
    )
    .ToListAsync();
```

Alternatively, if you're just getting the "raw" BsonDocument objects you can write:

```
List<BsonDocument> documents = await myCollection
    .Find(
        Builders<BsonDocment>.Filter.In("_id", documentsToLoad)
    )
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I assume your answer will run more efficiently than Alexandra's above? I feel as if your answer will be faster since it uses Mongo's Filter.In syntax rather than the standard C# .Contains

Comment: @walnut_salami I'm not 100% certain here, but I think they might be translated to effectively the same thing. I'm not sure about the efficiency of doing that conversion though.